# Is there a way to implement a generic class for displaying an object fields?

Tags: java, templates, generic-programming

I have some classes(e.g. Hospital, Doctor, Nurse etc) and I need to write a generic class that appends to a file an object of a different type. Each class a method that displays its fields, but I can't pass this error **"Cannot resolve method 'print' in T"**

Here is the code:

```
package Service;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteFileService<T>
{
    private static WriteFileService instance;

    private WriteFileService(){}

    public static WriteFileService getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public void appendObject(T object, String fileName)
    {
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);

            // creates the file if it does not exist
            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true); // append mode = true
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            object.print(bufferedWriter); //! ERROR: Cannot resolve method 'print' in T

            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Problem handling the files!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help regarding the method would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of type erasure your T is treated as Object (in runtime) and there is no `print()` method in Object class. 
You can add interface:

```
public interface Printable {
    void print();
}
```

and let all your classes implement it.
Then you would need to change this:

`public class WriteFileService<T>`

to this:

`public class WriteFileService<T extends Printable>`